# Can't receive journey builder emails because error queue

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a test Journey which contains a single email to send when triggered. I have triggered a number of records to go through this recently but they are stuck in the queue (5 in total), I've noticed there are also 10 errors.

When triggering new records into the Journey, the queue number goes up. The Journey itself is active, will the queue not be processed until the error number is cleared?

Answer (score 2):

Deploying a triggered send with unhandled errors will cause those records to queue up and prevent additional ones from processing until the the queue has been cleared and the trigger has been refreshed.

I'd make the necessary updates to your email, clear the queue and then either refresh both the TSD and email activity in the journey or just create a new draft and activate it.

Comment: The email is from Journey Builder, so it's not visible in Triggered Sends page. How can I clear the queue if they originate from Journey Builder?

Comment: Journey Builder email activities are triggered sends so you should be able to view them from your interactions menu in Email Studio. It will be in the "Journey Builder Sends" subfolder.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I can see the email in the queue but its stuck there. Does the error'ed emails (there are still 10 there, despite pausing and restarting) prevent the queue from being processed?

Comment: While I'm not sure that this is supposed to be the case, error'ed items in your queue can definitely hold up the entire trigger in my experience. When I encountered this issue in the past, nothing worked at all unless I cleared the entire queue and refreshed the TSD.